# How to give Noto Color Emoji highest precedence for rendering emoji (19.10)

Tags: fonts, chromium, emoji, brave

I started with a VM of Ubuntu 19.10. I applied all updates and installed Chromium and Brave Browser. When I try viewing emoji (E.G. getemoji.com) they appear to be rendered by DejaVu Sans (black and white). The system already has Noto Color Emoji installed.
How do I give Noto Color Emoji precedence? I've followed several fontconfig tutorials, but none of them have worked.
I've had success by reinstalling Noto Color Emoji, but I haven't been able to figure out what reinstalling is doing that makes it work. Also, I'm working with someone who says reinstalling did no work for him.

Answer (score 1):

One way:

1. Create this file:

   ```
   ~/.config/fontconfig/conf.d/10-prefer-emoji.conf
   ```
2. Give it this contents:

   ```
   <?xml version="1.0"?>
   <!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
   <fontconfig>
           <alias>
                   <family>sans-serif</family>
                   <prefer>
                           <family>Noto Color Emoji</family>
                   </prefer>
           </alias>
   </fontconfig>
   ```

*Edit:*

That seems not to be sufficient (see comment).

```
$ fc-match -a | head -2
DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
NotoColorEmoji.ttf: "Noto Color Emoji" "Regular"
```

So maybe change the contents to this variant:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<!DOCTYPE fontconfig SYSTEM "fonts.dtd">
<fontconfig>
        <match target="pattern">
        <test qual="any" name="family">
                <string>sans-serif</string>
        </test>
        <edit name="family" mode="prepend" binding="strong">
                <string>Noto Color Emoji</string>
        </edit>
        </match> 
</fontconfig>
```

That seems to make a difference:

```
 $ fc-match -a | head -2
 NotoColorEmoji.ttf: "Noto Color Emoji" "Regular"
 DejaVuSans.ttf: "DejaVu Sans" "Book"
```

Comment: I closed Chromium and Brave, ensured they didn't have background processes still running, created that file you specified with the contents you specified, ran "fc-cache -f", re-ran Chromium and Brave. They still render emoji with DejaVu Sans instead of Noto Color Emoji.

Comment: @denshigomi: I edited the answer.

Comment: The new file contents you provided change the output of "fc-match -a | head -2" showing Noto Color Emoji first. However, Chromium and Brave still render emoji using DejaVu Sans. I even rebooted to be sure I wasn't missing anything.

Comment: @denshigomi: Maybe they don't honor fontconfig. Do they have separate app specific font settings?

Comment: I'm not sure. What has me stumped is that if I run "sudo apt install --reinstall fonts-noto-color-emoji" then emoji are displayed using Noto Color Emoji. I extracted the deb file for it and compared filenames, locations, permissions, and checksums. They all match what is already on my system. So why does a reinstall fix it? I can see it runs some fontconfig command when it finishes installing, but I'm not 100% sure what it's doing. I thought it was just running a "fc-config -f", but clearly there's more to it. I've got to be missing something.