# Emojis Stop Working After Restarting Ubuntu (fonts-noto-color-emoji)

Tags: fonts, chromium, emoji

Because emojis are not displaying in Chromium I had to install `fonts-noto-color-emoji` via:

```
sudo apt reinstall fonts-noto-color-emoji
```

Then emojis work just fine.

But after restarting my machine emojis stop working again.

Is there something, that I have to configure to boot the package at startup? Or what is going wrong?

Comment: There is a [related question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1204255), and the OP of that question let us know that a reinstall of the `fonts-noto-color-emoji` package fixes it for the current session.

Comment: But this is exactly what I want to prevent... I don't want to install this package every time I reboot.... and the provided answer doesn't work either

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've just installed Ubuntu 20.04 and I no longer have the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a topic related to a bug that you described.

https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/fonts-noto-color-emoji/+bug/1859926

I fixed it using *denshigomi*'s suggestion:

> So far it seems a permanent workaround is to create a symlink to the noto color emoji files in the current user's ~/.fonts directory:

```
$ shopt -s dotglob; mkdir -p ~/.fonts/truetype/noto; ln -s /usr/share/fonts/truetype/noto/* ~/.fonts/truetype/noto
```