# How do I configure Ubuntu fonts to always use Source Pro family instead of Arial, Times, and Courier?

Tags: fonts

I never want to see Arial, Times New Roman, or for that matter, Courier, or any of their clones.

Instead, I want to configure my Ubuntu 20.04 to use Source Sans Pro, Source Serif Pro, and Source Code Pro respectively. I want to force these aliases on all applications, especially browsers.

I have a vague familiarity with the workings of fontconfig, but have never got it to actually do what I want.

Bonus points if we can get the Variable versions working!

Comment: There are quite a few answers at this site with examples of that kind of configuration. Look for instance at [this question](https://askubuntu.com/q/1204255).

Comment: Thanks, but that thread is dealing with a different change, and is full of "maybe", "seems", and "I must be missing something". I've had some experience of what that feels like. I don't want to fiddle with fontconfig in the hope that it might do what I want. I'm looking for some advice on making this specific change in a way that works.